# How to use to_date in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby 2.0

**controller action**

```
@date = "2013-12-21"
@new_date = @date.to_date
p @new_date
```

o/p: Sat, 21 Dec 2013

at view

```
<%= @new_date %>
```

o/p: 2013-12-21

i want on view "Sat, 21 Dec 2013"

Comment: use `@date` in your view...after applying `to_date`.. Did you do?

Comment: i tried but i am getting "2013-12-21"

Comment: Yes.. I got your point..Now.. I also faced the same issue what you are getting.

Comment: @new_date =  @date.to_date.strftime('%a, %e %b %y') this will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Rails* is so intelligent that it automatically calls](http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/dynamische_webseiten.html#erb-programmieren) all objects in a view that are not already a *string* via the method `.to_s`, which always converts the content of the object to a *string*.

Lets first dig me into the root cause, why such unexpected output :

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~/workspace/testproject$ rvm use 1.9.3
Using /home/kirti/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~/workspace/testproject$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.16)
1.9.3p484 :001 > d = "2013-12-21".to_date
 => Sat, 21 Dec 2013 
1.9.3p484 :002 > d.to_s
 => "2013-12-21" 
1.9.3p484 :003 > d
 => Sat, 21 Dec 2013 
1.9.3p484 :004 > d.class
 => Date 
1.9.3p484 :005 > d.strftime('%a, %e %b %Y')
 => "Sat, 21 Dec 2013" 
1.9.3p484 :006 >
```

`"2013-12-21".to_date` giving you a `Date` instance, not a `String` instance.`d.class` proved that. `d` is a `Date` instance, on which in view again `to_s` method is called as I told in the begining, so `Sat, 21 Dec 2013` is again set back into the `"2013-12-21"`. So your solution will be :

```
@date = "2013-12-21".to_date.strftime('%a, %e %b %Y')
```

`"2013-12-21".to_date.strftime('%a, %e %b %Y')` will give you the desired result as an `String` instance.So on *string* instance(***receiver***) if you apply `to_s`,you will get the same ***receiver*** back. Now you can use this `@date` variable in your view.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are getting

```
2013-12-21
```

but want

```
Sat, 21 Dec 2013
```

The reason it is outputted in the console nicely is because the console will auto format it for you. This can be verified by printing `@new_date.to_s` in the console, it'll be the unformatted version. To print it out on a screen in the way you want, you have to format it yourself.

You should use [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) like this:

```
@new_date = @new_date.strftime('%a, %e %b %Y')
```

or

```
@date.to_date.strftime('%a, %e %b %Y')
```

This will output Sat, 21 Dec 2013 correctly.

Comment: 2013-12-21 => "2013-12-21"

Comment: What do you mean by that comment?

Comment: make sure you've reassigned @new_date like I did.

Comment: undefined method `strftime' for "2013-12-21":String

Comment: @date = "2013-12-21" its a string

Comment: make sure you're using what you've called @new_date, i.e the date object (the one you called `to_date` on

Comment: or you could do this:

`@date.to_date.strftime('%a, %e %b %Y')`

Answer (score 0):

in Ruby 2.0 in a controller's action:

```
@date = "2013-12-21"

@new_date = @date.to_date

# => Sat, 21 Dec 2013
```

And use the `@new_date` on your view.

Answer (score 0):

```
@new_date.strftime('%a, %e %b %Y')
```

Use it directly on the view.

Comment: This is complete plagiarism

Comment: yeah, my answer.. maybe if you're new to SO, you should look at the guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but you should also look for that again may be you have forget.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to format a date object in Rails is by using the available [I18n formatters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).

```
<%= l @ new_date, format: :long %>
```

As described in the guide, you can also create additional formats. For example, if none of the defaults matches your desired format, simply define

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      custom: "%a, %e %b %Y"
```

then use

```
<%= l @ new_date, format: :custom %>
```